# How to implement Google Home Account synchronisation from my iOS application?

Tags: ios, swift, google-assistant-sdk, google-home, google-voice

We need to synchronize our account details to Google Home Account.

I can able to link the account details **FROM** Google Home App **TO** my iOS application. Also, I need to link the account details **FROM** my iOS application **TO** Google Home App.

We have referred the below document:
https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/implement-app-flip?OS=iOS#setup

In the above document, they have mentioned the App Flip option to link the account details from the Google Home app to my iOS app.

Comment: What account details are you trying to sync?

Comment: @NickFelker User needs to signup on to our server to use their smart devices, we have to configure that account details to the user's Google Home Application.

Comment: In order to manage that you can use App Flip, but that is a process that starts from the Google Home App and goes to your iOS app.